# Return values from an array that aren't null. Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, random, null

So I have this method below called catchAFish() that is meant to return a random object (Fish) from an array (fish). This method mostly works however I am trying to to make it not return any null elements while the number of Fish in the array is above zero. Once there are no more Fish objects in the array 'fish' then it is allowed to return null. I cannot use arraylists Here is my revised method:

```
public Fish catchAFish(){
    Fish aFish = null;
    if (numFish > 0){
        int idx = new Random().nextInt(fish.length);
        if (fish[idx] != null){
            aFish = fish[idx];
            numFish -= 1;
            fish[idx] = null;
        if (fish[idx] == null){
            catchAFish();}
    if (numFish == 0){
        ;}
        }}
return aFish;

}
```

Comment: Why not simply have a while loop that keeps looking until the fish returned is not null? This shouldn't be too hard for you to do. You would of course first need to check that the array is not full of nulls, and I assume that you have a fish count variable somewhere that would help you with this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That may take a while when you are trying to get the last of three fishes in, say, a 10,000-item array.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Yes, but judging from the code, I'd say that the OP is not ready to learn that lesson yet ...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: of course, but if you had to code a sparse array of that magnitude, you wouldn't use this type of set up. You wouldn't even likely back it with an array at all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is absolutely true - OP has an artificial "no `ArrayList`s" requirement, so it's likely that the use of other data structures is restricted as well.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to address this would be to generate a random index once, and then walk the array forward until you hit a non-null element, or go to the end of the array. Once you reach the end, reset the index back to zero, and continue on. If you reach the random index that you generated originally, then the array has no fish, and so you should return a `null`.

One problem with this approach is that the fish get unequal probability of being found: fishes with wider `null`-filled gaps in front of them are in higher danger of being caught. One way to fix this issue would be to herd all non-`null` fishes to the front of the array, keep the index of the last non-`null` fish, and move it in place of the random fish being removed from the array.

Comment: +1 - though herding fish is difficult unless you have a fish dog :-)